# Spaces between table cells that has no border

Tags: html, html-table

I just want to decrease the size of space between this two images I put in the table. I'm so sorry I know this is just a basic html code. Please help me.

[image]

This is the code:

```
<table class="sample" width="200" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" >
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="center">
    <a href="#" ><img src="images/reception2.png" alt="" /></a>
    </br>
    SERVICES
    </td>

<td align="center" valign="center">
<a href="#"><img src="images/services2.png"  alt="" /></a>
    </br>
    OFFERS
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please see the image above.. please someone help me :(

Comment: why do u use `table` instead of `div`? `div` is much more better than `table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to advise without seeing the CSS you are using. You could try adjusting the width of the table.

Demo here: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/VmQGzr

You can remove the inline style on your table and then target it in your CSS, like this:

```
.sample {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Change the width to whatever works.

Comment: I did exactly what you told me, but it didn't do anything :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use `margin` property of CSS. for your question `margin-right` for the SERVICES img and `margin-left` for the OFFERS img are proper solutions.

Try to add this snippet:

```
<img src="images/reception2.png" alt="" style="margin-right: -25px"/>

<img src="images/services2.png" alt="" style="margin-left: -25px"/>
```

Also, You can change the number range to finally find the suitable numbers.